# Wrong Logic in For Loop

Tags: python, nltk

I have 2 lists (company name and category name) that have strings in them:

```
    a1 = ['MAGIC', 'BUS']
    a2 = ['TRANSPORTATION' , 'SERVICES', 'GROUP']
```

I want to compare each word in list 1 with each word in list 2 and get a semantic similarity score for each pair using nltk. I know how to manually compare each word using the 'wn.path_similarity(word_1_in_a1, word_1_in_a2)' function but I want to be able to do this in a For Loop.

Below are the scripts I have:

```
    if len(a1)>len(a2):
       for x in range(len(a1)):
          company_broken_down[x] = wn.synset(a1[x] + '.n.01')
          for y in range(len(a2)):
              category_broken_down[y] = wn.synset(a2[y] + '.n.01')
          semantic_sim[x]=wn.path_similarity(company_broken_down[x], category_broken_down[y])
    else:
         for y in range(len(a2)):
            category_broken_down[y] = wn.synset(a2[y] + '.n.01')
            for x in range(len(a1)):
              company_broken_down[x] = wn.synset(a1[x] + '.n.01')
            semantic_sim[y]=wn.path_similarity(company_broken_down[x], category_broken_down[y])

    print(semantic_sim)
```

After I run the above script I got {0: 0.14285714285714285, 1: 0.058823529411764705, 2: 0.09090909090909091}, which is the result of matching the word 'BUS' in list a1 with every word in list a2. However, the first word in a1, 'MAGIC', was never used.

Does anyone know how I can correct my For Loop to make it output all 6 similarity scores? Thanks very much.

Comment: Just write it down on paper.  Go step by step.  What does your code do.  You'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwritting semantic_sim[y]. Try the below code where size of semantic_sim is len(a1)*len(a2):

```
  if len(a1)>len(a2):
        for x in range(len(a1)):
            company_broken_down[x] = wn.synset(a1[x] + '.n.01')
            for y in range(len(a2)):
                category_broken_down[y] = wn.synset(a2[y] + '.n.01')
                semantic_sim[x*len(a2) + y]=wn.path_similarity(company_broken_down[x], category_broken_down[y])
    else:
        for y in range(len(a2)):
            category_broken_down[y] = wn.synset(a2[y] + '.n.01')
            for x in range(len(a1)):
                company_broken_down[x] = wn.synset(a1[x] + '.n.01')
                semantic_sim[y*len(a1) + x]=wn.path_similarity(company_broken_down[x], category_broken_down[y])

    print(semantic_sim)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @tshree! This solved my problem completely. I am kinda new to for loops and I will spend some time to learn the logics you put inside the brackets but this is great :)